# Looking for a VBA solution to automate a manual summation process on specific criteria?

Tags: excel, vba

I really appreciate your help on this coding challenge!

Basically, I need to get total number of cars quantity in column L but I only need to count those car quantity where a particular part exist, like for each parts in COL A ( A3 to A6) I need to count the total bus number. For example, part number 415 ( cell A3) only exist in CAR 6 to 10, so the total number of cars in COL L will be 276. Similarly for part number 416 the total quantity of car will be 511. (please see below the picture attached)

Just wondering how can I get the total in VBA? I highly appreciate any help!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPhAZ.png)

I am expecting a VBA code[image]

Comment: All you need is a simple `SUMPRODUCT` formula, no VBA: `=SUMPRODUCT($B$1:$K$1,$B3:$K3)` and drag down.

Comment: thanks Ben, however my goal is to put it in a macro as the actual data i have is way bigger than this which has more than 500k rows. And, this data will grow even bigger in near future. So, that's why i'm trying to automate it

Comment: You can automate writing a formula.

Answer (score 0):

- As ***@BigBen***'s comment, `SUMPRODUCT` is the best approach.
- A small improvement is to dynamically determine the size of the source table.
- You may convert formuals to static values on the last column.

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    With Cells(3, LastCol).Resize(LastRow - 2)
        ' Debug.Print .Address
        ' Apply formula
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMPRODUCT(RC[-" & LastCol - 2 & "]:RC[-1],R1C2:R1C" & LastCol - 1 & ")"
        ' Convert Formulas to Values
        .Formula = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

---

- If you prefer not to use any Excel formulas as an intermediate step, the following code achieves the same result.

```vb
Sub Demo2()
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, iSum As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range, oSht as Worksheet
    Const HEADER_ROWS = 2
    Set oSht = Sheets("Sheet1") ' modify as needed
    LastRow = oSht.Cells(oSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = oSht.Cells(HEADER_ROWS, oSht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set rngData = oSht.Range("A1", oSht.Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
    arrData = rngData.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) + HEADER_ROWS To UBound(arrData)
        iSum = 0
        For j = 2 To LastCol - 1
            iSum = iSum + arrData(i, j) * arrData(1, j)
        Next
        arrData(i, LastCol) = iSum
    Next
    rngData.Value = arrData
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Populate Sum Products Using VBA

- You could use the formula

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT(B$1:F$1,B3:F3)
  ```

  and copy down

[image]

```
Sub PopulateTotalCount()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count - 2
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = rg.Columns.Count - 2
    
    Dim CarQty() As Variant:
    CarQty = rg.Rows(1).Resize(, cCount).Offset(, 1).Value
    
    Dim PartCounts() As Variant:
    PartCounts = rg.Resize(rCount, cCount).Offset(2, 1).Value
    
    Dim TotalCounts() As Long: ReDim TotalCounts(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, TotalCount As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        For c = 1 To cCount
            TotalCount = TotalCount + PartCounts(r, c) * CarQty(1, c)
        Next c
        TotalCounts(r, 1) = TotalCount
        TotalCount = 0
    Next r
    
    rg.Columns(rg.Columns.Count).Resize(rCount).Offset(2).Value = TotalCounts
    
    MsgBox "Total counts populated.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```